# why do i have to sign qa flavor in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle, key, sign, android-productflavors

i have this build config in my gradle file ?

```
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix ".debug"
        }
        qa {
            applicationIdSuffix ".qa"
            versionNameSuffix ".qa"
        }
    }
    sourceSets { debug { res.srcDirs = ['src/debug/res', 'src/debug/res/values'] } }
}
```

why when i am try to run qa it trow me and error for not having key for this flavor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only build type for which Gradle can build your project "out of the box" is `debug`, as the Android Plugin for Gradle knows to use the plugin-created debug signing keystore. For everything else, you either need to:

- Configure a separate signing keystore (e.g., for `release`)
- Initialize the new build type from the `debug` build type, akin to using a copy constructor, so it uses the same rules that `debug` does for signing

In the following sample, I want to define a new `mezzanine` build type, giving it the same signing configuration as I use for `release`. So, I use `mezzanine.initWith(buildTypes.release)` to set up `mezzanine` as a copy of `release`, then continue to configure it with different rules:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.1"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('HelloConfig.keystore')
            keyAlias 'HelloConfig'
            storePassword 'laser.yams.heady.testy'
            keyPassword 'fw.stabs.steady.wool'
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
          applicationIdSuffix ".d"
          versionNameSuffix "-debug"
        }

        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        mezzanine.initWith(buildTypes.release)

        mezzanine {
            applicationIdSuffix ".mezz"
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, you would use something like `qa.initWith(buildTypes.debug)` before configuring the rest of the `qa` build type.

Comment: i hade a feeling only debug generate it's own key if you didn't request other wise , i can't use debug key for my qa flavor ? i need it for different package  name for the abilty to have both versions on my phone . thanks for the answer by the way very detail and helpful

Comment: @JesusDimrix: "i can't use debug key for my qa flavor ?" -- `qa` is a build type, according to your question. You can use the debug signing key for `qa` as outlined in my answer.